# OSError: [WinError 127] after gdal installation

Tags: python, django, pip, gdal, geodjango

I have just finished installing gdal 3.6 on Windows, and it looks like my django project is getting the file correctly. But when I run django manage.py check, it gives me the following output:

```
File "C:\users\rodri\dev\mymap\.mymap\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\gdal\libgdal.py", line 69, in <module>
    lgdal = CDLL(lib_path)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_3.12.752.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 379, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
OSError: [WinError 127] Não foi possível encontrar o procedimento especificado
```

Did someone already get through it, or knows how to fix it?

-- Edited --
It seems there are an amount of libs missing.OSGeo4W is properly installed. So what could be missing?

Full log:

```
...
File "C:\Users\rodri\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\apps.py", line 27, in ready
    self.module.autodiscover()
  File "C:\Users\rodri\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\__init__.py", line 50, in autodiscover
    autodiscover_modules("admin", register_to=site)
  File "C:\Users\rodri\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\django\utils\module_loading.py", line 58, in autodiscover_modules
    import_module("%s.%s" % (app_config.name, module_to_search))
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_3.12.752.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 90, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1387, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1360, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1331, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 935, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 995, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 488, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\rodri\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\admin\__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.admin.options import GeoModelAdmin, GISModelAdmin, OSMGeoAdmin
  File "C:\Users\rodri\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\admin\options.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.admin.widgets import OpenLayersWidget
  File "C:\Users\rodri\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\admin\widgets.py", line 5, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.gdal import GDALException
  File "C:\Users\rodri\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\gdal\__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.gdal.datasource import DataSource
  File "C:\Users\rodri\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\gdal\datasource.py", line 40, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.gdal.driver import Driver
  File "C:\Users\rodri\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\gdal\driver.py", line 5, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.gdal.prototypes import ds as vcapi
  File "C:\Users\rodri\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\gdal\prototypes\ds.py", line 9, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.gdal.libgdal import lgdal
  File "C:\Users\rodri\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\gdal\libgdal.py", line 71, in <module>
    lgdal = CDLL(lib_path)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_3.12.752.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 379, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
OSError: [WinError 127] Não foi possível encontrar o procedimento especificado
```

Comment: Taking a look on the web, it seems an unmatch between Django version (5.0.2) and GDal version (gdal306.dll). If it is really what is happening, does someone have a hint or direction about where to look at it? From django documentation, I understand that the lates version of django support up to 307 version of Gdal...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the problem was the Python version I was using (3.12). What I have done was creating a new conda environment and specified python for version 3.10.

All worked out smoothly since then.